# Downgrade Phalcon from previous version?

Tags: phalcon

Im running in Ubuntu 15 and installed Phalcon v3 but i have an issue with our current working API which is using v2 of Phalcon, is there a way to downgrade the current version of Phalcon that i'd installed to the previous v2?

Comment: Perhaps this post can help you?
https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/6512/how-to-downgrade-phalcon-2-to-13

Answer (score 4):

Usually, during compilation of Phalcon, you would execute this command. By default it will clone the `master` branch.

```
 git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git
```

But to select a specific branch, you need to add the `branch` parameter to the end of your command.

```
 git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git --branch 2.0.0
```

Now just run the other commands to (re)compile Phalcon

```
cd cphalcon/build
sudo ./install
```

You can check all the other available branches on github (see image below)
[image]