# Downgrade Phalcon 2.0 to 1.3 OS X

Tags: php, homebrew, phalcon

I installed phalcon using homebrew but I need to downgrade for the time being to 1.3 and can't find any documentation on how to do this with on osx.

Thanks

Comment: Asking for tutorials/documentation is EXPLICITLY off-topic

Comment: Before your question gets deleted, you may want to take a look on this lovely guide that Timothy made: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38710352/downgrade-phalcon-from-previous-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best answer for OSX users I found from Phalcon forums.

```
git clone https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon
cd cphalcon/build
git checkout 1.3.4
sudo ./install
```